# VBA - Error when plotting charts inside userform

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to display some data in charts inside a userform (userform2). The columns of data that populate the charts are previously calculated using another userform (userform1).

There are checkboxes in userform2 to enable the user to select the data to be ploted in the x axis. It also allows for more than one series to be plotted at once.

I've tested my code previously in another excel document and it worked fine, but when I tried to use it in the desired file it presented a weird behavior: the chart is creating lots of extra series I didn't ask for which are labeled with the text of the top cell (this is a merged cell that displays a title and goes from A1 to L1).

I've tried to fix the issue by copying the columns that should populate the charts to a blank worksheet once userform1 was terminated. Eventhough the cells are correctly copied, the resulting chart keeps on presenting the same errors, plotting data from worksheet1 that shouldn't appear in the graph.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If CheckBox1 = False And CheckBox2 = False And CheckBox3 = False Then

    MsgBox "Select a chart to be plotted"
    Exit Sub

End If

Dim MyChart As Chart
Dim ChartData1 As Range
Dim ChartData2 As Range
Dim ChartData3 As Range
Dim ChartName1 As String
Dim ChartName2 As String
Dim ChartName3 As String

Set ChartData1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B13")
ChartName1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")

Set ChartData2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2:C13")
ChartName2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1")

Set ChartData3 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D2:D13")
ChartName3 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set MyChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers).Chart

MyChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

If CheckBox1 = True Then
MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = ChartName1
MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = ChartData1
MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A13")
End If

MyChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
If CheckBox2 = True Then
MyChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = ChartName2
MyChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = ChartData2
MyChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A13")
End If

MyChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
If CheckBox3 = True Then
MyChart.SeriesCollection(3).Name = ChartName3
MyChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = ChartData3
MyChart.SeriesCollection(3).XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A13")
End If

Dim imageName As String
imageName = Application.DefaultFilePath & Application.PathSeparator & "TempChart.gif"
MyChart.Export Filename:=imageName, FilterName:="GIF"

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Delete
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
UserForm2.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(imageName)
End Sub
```

Also, I have to use the command line `MyChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries` before the `If` loops so even when only one checkbox is marked there are labels for 3 series (with generic titles). Is there a way around it?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: When you set the chartnames with `ChartName1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")` you take values out of your merged cell `(A1:L1)` which is the title, don't you?

Comment: It really shouldn't take the title, cause this merged cell is in whorksheet1 and the cells I'm using to populate the charts are in the worksheet2,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by plotting the graph in worksheet 2 instead of plotting it in worksheet 1. I don't see why the code was failing at first, but the changes solved the problem, so it's ok.

All I did was change all the `ActiveSheet` to `Worksheets("Sheet2")`. Then, instead of using the data from worksheet2 and plotting it in worksheet 1, I do it all in worksheet 2. That doesn't really matter, since the chart will actually be displayed in the userform.